# Let's make [repair] disposable

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[repair](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/repair) is a meta tag that can be applied to anything and has been (370 questions). Since we have few experts in repairing everything, this should be cleaned up by re-tagging with existing (and new) subject-specific tags.

Answer (score -8):

One can combine [repair](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/repair) with other tags to get more specific.

Comment: It'd still be a meta tag, and not a useful one at that. Presumably almost every question here could be someone trying to "repair" a software issue.